# Designing an Python API: Fluent interface or arguments

Tags: python, interface-design

I'm playing around with a simple port of the [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/) API to Python.

Consider the simple bar chart example, in Javascript:

```
var vis = new pv.Panel()
    .width(150)
    .height(150);

vis.add(pv.Bar)
    .data([1, 1.2, 1.7, 1.5, .7, .3])
    .width(20)
    .height(function(d) d * 80)
    .bottom(0)
    .left(function() this.index * 25);

vis.render();
```

I'm debating whether to continue to use this fluent interface style API or use named parameters instead.  With named parameters we could write:

```
vis = pv.Panel(width=150,
               height=150)

vis = vis + pv.Bar(data=[1, 1.2],
                   width=20,
                   height=lambda d: d * 80,
                   bottom=0,
                   left=lambda: self.index * 25)
vis.render()
```

Is there a preferred Python style?

Comment: Interesting. I've seen both. For e.g. Django uses both: method chainsand keyword arguments.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I think it's both ugly :P

Comment: The advantage of the keyword syntax is that you can use something like `pv.Bar(**kwargs)` more easily than with the fluent API. Also, as I've seen it in JavaScript with jQuery, a lot of anonymous functions are used - these don't map well to Python.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My vote is anti-chaining, pro-named-params.

1. dot-chaining makes for poor code-intellisense since the empirical prototype is just an empty Panel() or Bar(), you can of course pydoc on it, but in this day and age intellisense is available in most IDEs and a great productivity booster.
2. Chaining makes programatically calling the class much more difficult. It's very nice to be able to pass in a list or dict as *args, **kwargs -- while possible with chaining you'd basically have to support both methods or a bunch of backflips to meta-create the class.
3. Chaining makes code more difficult to read because inevitably someone will do it all on one line, and wonder why things are all goofed up when they've passed in the same param twice -- you can prevent that but with a named param constructor dup filtering is basically built in.